# Jest client - create multiple type mappings at once

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

Is there a way I can create multiple type mappings in one go using Jest?

I have to create mappings with parent-child relationships and this can only be done if the mapping for the various types are created in one request.

Comment: found a solution ?

Comment: At the time this was not possible with Jest. I don't think it is now either. What I ended up doing was creating an index configuration json file and just posting to the [create index endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-index) of Elasticsearch using [org.apache.http](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html). No jest involved for this step.